# YSLow says certain CSS are not gzipped

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, gzip

YSlow keeps on telling me files like http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/q-and-a/css/q-a-plus.css?ver=1.0.6.2 are not gzipped while the gzip test tool at [Feed the Bot](http://www.feedthebot.com/tools/gzip/) mentions I am all good:

```
Compressed? Yes
Compression type    gzip
Page size (Bytes)   32,493
Compressed size (Bytes) -1
Saving (Bytes)  32,494
Compression %   100%
```

I added this to my .htaccess:

```
# Gzip

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

#Deflate

<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

The header for the file mentioned states:

```
CF-Cache-Status MISS
CF-RAY  13945df90a9a0c1d-AMS
Cache-Control   public, max-age=2592000
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Content-Type    application/javascript
Date    Thu, 12 Jun 2014 07:34:38 GMT
Expires Sat, 12 Jul 2014 07:34:38 GMT
Last-Modified   Thu, 21 Feb 2013 01:29:18 GMT
Server  cloudflare-nginx
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

Is my code for gzipping correct here?

Comment: I assume `me.com` is in reality your own domain, not Apple's iCloud service? In that case, edit it to be `example.com`.

Comment: I have adjusted the url @SvW . Yeah, it should be a dummy url. Have had this issue before, but now that I saw it again I want to deal with it once and for all.

Comment: That "Feed the Bot" tool is obviously broken.

Comment: Are you sure those headers are for the same file? "Content-Type: application/javascript" sounds rather odd for a CSS file.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist I have 12 files that are not gzipped according to YSlow and most are CSS. Almost all end with a version string `?ver=x`. Another example of a CSS file not being gzipped according to YS is `http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/q-and-a/css/q-a-plus.css?ver=1.0.6.2` Perhaps I need to add another mime handler or mime include besides the include line `mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$`?